# Função mysql_insert_id() retorna apenas zero

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Pessoal estou com problemas com a função mysql_insert_id(), quando utilizo da forma abaixo o valor retornado é sempre "0" (zero). Podem me ajudar?

A função "add" chama a função "save".

FUNÇÃO OPEN_DATABASE

```
// ABRE A BASE DE DADOS
function open_database()
{
    try
        {
            $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
            return $conn;
        }
    catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return null;
        }
}
```

FUNÇÃO ADD

```
// INSERE NOVO ORÇAMENTO
function add()
{
    if (!empty($_POST['budget']))
        {
            $budget = $_POST['budget'];
            save('budgets', $budget);
            //print_r($budget);
            //header('location: view.php?id='.$id);
        }
}
```

FUNÇÃO SAVE

```
// INSERE UM NOVO REGISTRO NO BANCO DE DADOS
function save($table = null, $data = null)
{
    $database = open_database();
    $columns = null;
    $values = null;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $columns .= trim($key, "'") . ", ";
            $values .= "'$value', ";
        }
    // remover a ultima vÍrgula
    $columns = rtrim($columns, ', ');
    $values = rtrim($values, ', ');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " ($columns) " . "VALUES " . "($values);";
    //echo $sql;
    try
        {
            $database -> query($sql);
            $id = mysql_insert_id();
            header('location: view.php?id='.$id);
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registro cadastrado com sucesso!';
            $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        }
    catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Nao foi possivel realizar a operacao!';
            $_SESSION['type'] = 'danger';
        }
    close_database($database);
}
```

Comment: Pergunta: o registro é salvo corretamente no banco de dados?

Comment: As funções antigas `mysql_` não lançam exception, o `try-catch` fica so de enfeite.

Comment: Provavelmente você está usando outro driver para conectar ao banco, o que é bom, já que `mysql_` está obsoleto e foi descontinuado. A resposta depende de como é a sua função `open_database`, inclua o conteúdo dela na pergunta.

Comment: @bfavaretto está atualizada...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim, é salvo normalmente...

Comment: Faltou um `i` na chamada e passar a conexão para função.

Comment: Isto é, `mysqli_insert_id($database)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está usando mysqli e na linha  `$id = mysql_insert_id();` usou mysql

Faltou também passar a conexão  `$database` para a função  `$id = mysqli_insert_id($database);`

```
    ..........
    ..........
    try
    {
        $database -> query($sql);
        $id = mysqli_insert_id($database);
        header('location: view.php?id='.$id);
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registro cadastrado com sucesso!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';

    ..........
    ..........
```